# Counters incremented too many times in a beamer presentation with overlays

Tags: beamer, counters, overlays

It seems that a frame with overlays in Beamer needs to be processed multiple times. The problem is that a counter that should only be incremented once is incremented more than expected.

How to avoid counters to be incremented multiple times in a Beamer presentation with overlays ?

### Minimal working example

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newcounter{Test}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Should be 0: \theTest
    \stepcounter{Test}\pause
    \item Should be 1: \theTest
    \stepcounter{Test}\pause
    \item Should be 2: \theTest
    \stepcounter{Test}\pause   
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: Output]

Comment: `beamer` treats every slide as a separate chunk of code and executes them as many times as the number of slides. So it reads the counter incrementing lines more than you issue them.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Add `\resetcounteronoverlays{Test}` to your preamble

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newcounter{Test}
\resetcounteronoverlays{Test}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Should be 0: \theTest
    \stepcounter{Test}\pause
    \item Should be 1: \theTest
    \stepcounter{Test}\pause
    \item Should be 2: \theTest
    \stepcounter{Test}\pause
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

See section 9.6 of the manual

Comment: Simple as that... I lost one hour today because of this tiny issue! Thank you.

Comment: thank you very much, I tried to obtained this long, not obvious to find it in a doc.