# Exercise numbering with overlays in beamer

Tags: beamer, counters, overlays, exercises

In would like to use the `exercise` package in a beamer presentation (this allows me to keep the conventions I use in the corresponding paper document).

This works well except that exercise numbers are changing with overlays. How can I avoid Exercise counter to be affected by beamer overlays ?

Here is a simple example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{exercise}

\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\begin{document}

 \begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Title}

  \begin{Exercise}
   This is the content of my exercise.
  \end{Exercise}
  \pause
  \begin{block}{A block which appears later}
   This is the content of my block.
  \end{block}
 \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Comment: This one is a bit cleaner than the one you found, so probably less side effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a hack which do the job, thanks to [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/331252/46718):

Adding the following lines to the preamble do the job for me:

```
\newcounter{preFrameExerciseCounter}

\AtBeginEnvironment{frame}{\setcounter{preFrameExerciseCounter}{\value{Exercise}}}

\let\originalframe=\frame
\def\frame{\originalframe\setcounter{Exercise}{\value{preFrameExerciseCounter}}}
```

[image: MWE]

---

EDIT : much better solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/201320/46718). Instead of the code given above, simply use in your preamble:

```
 \resetcounteronoverlays{Exercise}
```